# Cloudfront redirects to S3 endpoint

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

1. I've set up a cloudfront distribution using Endpoint address.
2. I want to redirect calls to the `/Latest` folder to the `/12.50` folder.
3. So I defined a redirect rule in the S3 console, using the routing rules markup.

[image: routing rule]

**Result:** the redirect kicks in, but moves the user from the cloudfront URL to the endpoint URL.

e.g. A user who comes in at `<mysite>.cloudfront.net/Latest` gets redirected to `<bucket>.hpe-alm.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/12.50`.

**Question:** is there a way for the redirect to keep the user on the cloudfront domain?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than performing the redirect within Amazon S3, you could change the **origin path** within CloudFront.

- Define an origin with an **origin path** of `/12.50`
- Edit the **behaviour** of the CloudFront distribution when you want it to point to a different version

Here's some examples:

**Full redirect**

In this case, I re-pointed the root (`dxxx.cloudfront.net`) to a sub-directory:

- I created an **Amazon S3 bucket** and applied a bucket policy to make it all publicly readable
- I created **two folders** in the bucket: `v1` and `v2`
- I uploaded two different pictures to each folder, but with the same filename
- I created an **Amazon CloudFront distribution two Origins**, pointing to `v1` and `v2` respectively
- I set the distribution's **default behaviour** to point to the `v1` origin
- Once the distribution was ready, I accessed `dxxx.cloudfront.net/picture.jpg`. It returned the picture from `v1`.
- I then modified the behaviour to point to the `v2` origin. Once the distribution was ready, I accessed the same URL and it returned the picture from `v2`.

**Redirect of a sub-directory**

In this example, I re-pointed `dxxx.cloudfront.net/Latest` to a different sub-directory.

The important difference is that the destination subdirectory has to contain a `/Latest` subdirectory, since it is actually pointing to `dxxx.cloudfront.net/<version>/Latest`, with only the `<version>` portion being substituted.

- To the above example, I added a `/Latest` folder within the `v1` and `v2` subdirectories and put pictures in each of them
- I added an extra **behaviour** with a **Path Pattern** of `/Latest/*` pointing to the `v1` origin
- Once the distribution was ready, I accessed `dxxx.cloudfront.net/Latest/picture.jpg`. It returned the picture from `/Latest/v1`.
- I then modified the `/Latest` behaviour to point to the `v2` origin. Once the distribution was ready, I accessed the same URL and it returned the picture from `/Latest/v2`.

Comment: Thanks. It's not clear to me which setting in Behavior allows me to redirect requests to `/Latest` to `12.50`. **Path pattern** redirects to the bucket again.

Comment: I did some experimentation and added some examples.